# I can't save widget and loading images

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem when I want to add a new widget or to record changes in the existing ones. When I enable "accessibility mode" it works.

I also have a problem when I add existing images, it will not display them in the gallery. I can add a new image but can not see the current. Circle that shows that the action in the course of constantly revolving.

[image: Save Widget]

[image: Media library]

[image: Add imaage]

Comment: Open up your developer console. Any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Failed to load resource: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I'd check with your host to see if mod security rule is being triggered

Answer (score 0):

I slove problem with "define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');" in wp-config.php